# How to add remove accessory to custom cell?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to have "delete accessory" for custom cell.
[image]

I overrided `canEditRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }
```

Set attributes here(But where remove accessory ??):

[image]

But this doesn't work for me.

Comment: It only appears when in edit mode.

Comment: how to turn on edit mode ? i thought ```canEditRowAtIndexPath``` this method do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the editing functionality, you need to tell the table view to edit. Somewhere (probably in an action for a `UIBarButtonItem`):

```
tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
```

In order to remove editing functionality, you need to tell the table view to stop editing. Somewhere else (probably in the same action):

```
tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
```

Note that `editButtonItem()` will automatically create a `UIBarButtonItem` with this functionality.